# How show all photos in an album with just one UIImageView?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I know this:

```
imageView.image = aImage
```

Now I want to show many photos, i.e, all photos in an album.

```
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers(Array(photoIDSet), options: nil)
let imageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
imageRequestOptions.synchronous = true
imageRequestOptions.resizeMode = .Fast

fetchResult.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({
    fetchedObject, _, _ in
    if let asset = fetchedObject as? PHAsset{
        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: specialSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: imageRequestOptions, resultHandler: {
            image, _ in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                imageView.image = image
            })
        })
    }
})
```

The Code above doesn't work as expected. It will just change one time if lucky.

IS there a way?

Comment: Create an array of assets. Fetch images from assets one by one and show them by keeping a delay of 1 second between two images.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem. The whole enumerateObjectsUsingBlock() method run in the one runloop, when the enumerate method run out, it commit just one change to imageView, the last image.

How to fix it? Use `- performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to call the function self at the end of function. Remember leave a exit.